# SQL Server prepared request with a list of values

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm doing a request to a DWH which is very long so I will just point where my problem is:

```
DW_PUR_OrderlineActual.LogComp In (11,18,54,68,92,159,164)
```

I'm doing this condition in a where clause and I would like to do it in a prepared request. In fact I have a List with the different values that go in this condition and I would like to have somthing like this:

```
DW_PUR_OrderlineActual.LogComp In ?
```

In which I could replace the "?" with my list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause). Look at the answer provided by Mark Brackett on December 3, 2008.

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks all for your help ! Can you tell me what I need to do with this post ? I delete it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is to load a long list of values to the database. I have successfully used the [SqlBulkCopy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to load as many as 10,000 rows per second for simple dumps into a single table. The usage is pretty straightforward. You can pass it an array of DataRow objects, a DataTable, or a DataReader that it can read from.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not looking for performance. I just need to know how can I do a prepared request with what I said before in a where clause. And I want to fill the "?" with a list of values. Do you know how I can do it ?